# Having trouble creating a new object from a class in Eclipse

Tags: java

Eclipse says there's an error with the keyword "new" and "dog" in the following code, but I've copied this example straight off a book. I don't know what's wrong here

Eclipse error #1:Dog cannot be resolved to a variable
error #2:syntax error on token "new", delete this token

```
package pkg;

// creating the Dog class
class Dog {
    int size;
    String breed;
    String name;

    void bark(){
        System.out.println("Ruff! Ruff!");
    }
}

// this function does the testDrive
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // problem occurs here, both "new" and "dog" underlined
        Dog d = new Dog;
        d.size = 40;
        d.bark();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the constructor braces, more specifically:

```
Dog d = new Dog();
```

Comment: Not a problem, glad it helped.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say `new Dog()`, not just `new Dog`.

Alas, Java is not C++; you don't get to omit the brackets just because you're using the default constructor.