# Very first Java example in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I've been asked to enter the following example into Eclipse

Paste the following snippet of code into a Java application using Eclipse. There may be some errors in the code that you'll need to correct <== errors???

```
                Properties p = System.getProperties();
                Enumeration<Object> keys = p.keys();
                while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
                String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
                String value = (String)p.get(key);
                System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
                }
```

But Eclipse is giving me errors.

Also What's the difference between Eclipse Classic and Java EE.

Comment: Go back to whoever asked you to enter that and tell them to give you the rest of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just a code fragment, you need to build some extra class "infrastructure" around it, and a function.

To see what I mean by "infrastructure" have a look at your previous Java question ( [Having trouble creating a new object from a class in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7290701/having-trouble-creating-a-new-object-from-a-class-in-eclipse) )

Regarding Eclipse, Eclipse is a modular editor and the several editions are bundles of the basic editor and a set of modules geared specifically to the development in a certain environment.  The Java EE Edition comes with pre-integrated modules for typical tasks and APIs in Java Enterprise Edition, like JPA (persistence), JSF (presentation), enterprise project packaging and so on.  A complete list (for Indigo) can he consulted [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigor).

Comment: The brace is not dangling, it's closing one at the `while` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class DumbEclipseExample {

    public static void main(String [] args) { 
        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        Enumeration<Object> keys = p.keys();
        while (keys.hasMoreElements()) {
            String key = (String)keys.nextElement();
            String value = (String)p.get(key);
            System.out.println(key + ": " + value);
        }
    }
}
```

I'd write it this way:

```
public class SlightlyLessStupidEclipseExample {

    public static void main(String [] args) { 

        Properties p = System.getProperties();
        for (String key : p.keySet()) {
            System.out.printf("%s : %s\n", key, p.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

Less code is better.